# Ng Build in prod mode generates vendor files and .Map file even when using - ng build --base-href # --prod --source-map=false --build-optimizer --aot

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have a Higher version of Angular Cli(6.1.4) globally installed and my project Angular Cli(1.7.4) is lower.

I'm running build in production mode an  trying get read of separate   vendor .js file and all .map files.

I tired below commands with build-optimizer and making source map to false but still i can see dist folder contains these file.

i'm getting style.bundle.js instead style.bundle.css.

ng build --base-href # --prod --source-map=false --build-optimizer --aot.

Does global CLi causing this issue?

[Global CLI-](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S7Trt.png)

[Local CLI-](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJD9U.png)

[Build status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dAJwt.png)

Answer (score 0):

Angular CLI  --prod flag takes care of removing map files, Remove the equal sign in your command and replace it with space.

Comment: i have already used these commands - 

ng build --base-href # --prod --source-map=false --build-optimizer --aot.   



ng build --base-href # --prod  --build-optimizer --aot.

no luck, i even modified tsconfig.json where i made sourceMap to false but still  it generates .map files

Comment: Are you saying you removed = and it still didn't work?

Comment: yes as  i said i tired these two commands -
1.   ng build --base-href # --prod --source-map=false --build-optimizer --aot


2.  ng build --base-href # --prod --build-optimizer --aot

and i even set sourceMap to false in tsConfig.json

but same result

Comment: i found the cause of it. i was running these commands in  git bash and  not in command prompt. i just tried this on command prompt and got the desired result.